# Calling service function on resource success callback in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service that make a REST call. When the rest call is complete (i.e. the data is available), I want to call the service's function which process that data.

```
.service('EventService', function(eventRestApi, $scope) { 
     var internalData = { messages : [], headers: [], consolidatedEvents : {} }
     return {    
         loadEvents : function(beginTimeMillis, endTimeMillis) { 
            this.getEvents(beginTimeMillis, endTimeMillis, internalData, null)
                .then(function(result){
                    internalData.consolidatedEvents = this.consolidateEvents(internalData.events)
                })  
         },
         getEvents : function() {...},
         consolidatedEvents : function() {...},
     }
```

I get an error saying that `this` doesn't have `consolidateEvents`. How do I access a function in my service on a callback? Am I approaching this problem wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In a callback, 'this' become your callback, so to access it you can link the parent scope in a variable.

I recommend that :

```
.service('MyService', function () {
    var that = this;
    return {
            myCallback : function () {
                    that.myMethod();
            }
    }
});
```